# Solving an ODE using Picards Iteration technique

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL4vP.png)

[image]

Please note I have solved parts a and b, I have also calculated the value of $L$ using the formula given, however I don't know how to calculate for $M$. It says $\max|f(t,y)|$ so am I supposed to use $y(t)=y_o+f(t_o,y_o)\,(t-t_o)$? I used that but then $y(t)$ will be $0$ and therefore $\max|f(t,y)|$ will become only $t^2$. The value of $t$ which I got while calculating $L$ is $1.03393$ and using that $h<1/L$ condition is satisfied, however $Mh<b$ condition is not being satisfied.

Can someone help me on this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A similar task (but for a different ODE) of determining a rectangle for the Picard fixed-point iteration was discussed in [The IVP $\dot{x}=x^3+e^{-t^2}$, $x(0)=1$ possesses a solution in $I=(-1/9,1/9)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2622702/115115)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulation of part b) is somewhat ambiguous. What is meant is that the function $f$ is defined as $f(t,y)=t^2+y^2$, and then the differential equation, the classical quadratic Riccati equation, is $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))=t^2+y(t)^2$. The first is an ordinary function definition, the second a functional equation for $y(t)$.

Thus the easiest part is to determine the bounds,
$$
M=\max_{|t|\le h,\,|y|\le b} |f(t,y)|=h^2+b^2,
$$
and the Lipschitz constant is determined from
$$
|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|\le 2b|y_1-y_2|
$$
as $L=2b$.

Now you have to balance the equations
$$
q=Lh=2bh<1~\text{ and }~ Mh=(b^2+h^2)h\le b.
$$
(Or use strict inequalities everywhere). Or rather confirm that indeed with $h=\frac12$ you get $q=b=\frac17<1$ and $Mh=\frac1{98}+\frac18<\frac17\iff 98>56$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I got it now, :)