# Interval of solution from Picard iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Respected Sir/Madam,
Kindly suggest me the method I can solve it or resource to learn it

Consider the initial value problem(IVP) 
$$y'=y^3+e^{−5t},~~
 y(0)=4/10 .$$
Then, the solution of the above initial value problem exists on the interval

Thank You,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is apparently some kind of homework problem. Meaning that techniques useful to solve it have been discussed previously. What are they, what difficulties do you have applying them. Have you looked for similar problems here? Also, please decide on either the interval that the Picard iteration converges (in the sense of the usual local existence proof), or the maximal domain of a solution.

Comment: Your question is very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2622702/115115. Tell us if that already answers your question or what the specific problems are in applying those ideas here.

Comment: No that doesn't answers it. I want to know how do I define a domain for the solution of that ode. Thank you

Comment: You can't, there is no way to get a symbolic solution or some kind of reduction to a simple quadrature for this problem. You can apply numerical solvers to get close approximation of the boundaries, or construct the situation for the fixed-point theorem in the existence proof that gives some interval that is usually drastically smaller than the maximal domain. // Is the initial value correctly reproduced as $y(0)=410$ or was that originally $4/10=2/5$ or something totally different?

Comment: Yes it is 4/10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an exploration of what is close to the maximally achievable. The interval approximation that is found is not exactly proven. In the task, you are probably expected to find a much smaller interval, a box $(t,y) =[t_0-a,t_0+a]\times[y_0-b,y_0+b]$ where the direct Picard iteration is contracting in the unmodified supremum norm.

---

To compute a numerical approximation for the inner interval, consider the vector field $(1, e^{-5t}+y^3)$ and rescale it to grow at most linearly in $y$ by dividing by $(1+y^2)$. Then solve for instance on $[-10,10]$

```
function dotu = f(s,u)
    t = u(1); y = u(2);
    a = 1+y^2;
    dotu = [1/a; (y^3+exp(-5*t))/a];
end;

[sneg, uneg] = ode45(@f, [0,-8], [0;4/10]);
[spos, upos] = ode45(@f, [0, 5], [0;4/10]);
% interval bounds
disp([uneg(end,1), upos(end,1)]);
% a better pole position estimate
t2=upos(end,1); y2=upos(end,2);
disp([t2 + 1/(2*y2^2)]);
clf;
hold on
plot(uneg(:,1),-exp(-5/3*uneg(:,1)),'g');
plot(uneg(:,1),uneg(:,2), '-+r');
plot(upos(:,1),upos(:,2),'-xb');
grid on; hold off;
```

resulting in the interval bounds  $[ -1.024183468244184,\,   1.548175031612699]$. Increasing the integration interval will lead to an increasing negative bound, while in the positive direction the curve grows in $y$, but stays almost stationary in $t$, that is, there is a pole.

[image]

One could now speculate that on the small positive segment, the ODE is bounded below by $y'=y^3\implies y(t)^{-2}=y_0^{-2}-2(t-t_0)$, giving a pole for the lower bound and thus an upper bound for the domain of the solution at $t_0+\frac1{2\cdot 0.4^2}=3.125$. This is not a very good bound, but it shows that the domain on that side is bounded at all. Taking the last computed point $(t_2,y_2)$ as initial value, one can get a better estimate for the pole by using this approximation as $t^*=t_2+\frac1{2y_2^2}= 1.54962150$.

On the left side the transient $y=-e^{-5t/3}$ is also an attracting asymptote, so that the solution will eventually follow it and exist on the full half-axis.