# Prove that there is a solution to a Cauchy problem on a given segment.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

> There's a Cauchy problem:
>   $$
> y'=x+y^3,\ \ y(0)=0
> $$
>   Prove that there is a solution to this problem on the segment $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$

First, I tried to solve the given differential equation. But I got stuck, since the equation is non-linear. So, I thought that there must be a differet approach to this problem.
Could anyone give me a hint how I can deal with this task?

Comment: See [Interval of solution from Picard iteration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3530248/115115) and [The IVP $\dot{x}=x^3+e^{-t^2}$, $x(0)=1$ possesses a solution in $I=(-1/9,1/9)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2622702/115115) for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the box $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$, $a=\frac12$, the function value of the right side has a bound of $M=a+b^3$ and a Lipschitz constant $L=3b^2$.

The growth bound condition $Ma\le b$ and the contraction condition $La<1$, which written out are 
$$
\frac12+b^3\le 2b ~\text{ and }~ b^2<\frac23,
$$ 
can be satisfied for $b=\frac13$. So indeed a solution exists on this interval.

This same method can be used to get larger intervals, 
$$
a^2+ab^3\le b\land 3ab^2\le 1
$$
can still be satisfied with $a=b=\frac23$.

The numerical solution shows a pole at about $x=1.6475$

[image: plot of numerical solution]

Comment: +1 nice answer as usual Lutz